# There is no tmp/restart.txt file in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I use Passenger to start my Rails app, but after I started Nginx, Rails app works fine, but I can't find any `restart.txt` file under `tmp` dir.

Is it to be created automatically by Passenger or manual? If automatically why doesn't it exist?

Comment: This is the first result when I search for "touch tmp/restart.txt". Is this a passenger-specific way of restarting your server? The command is included in the `bin/setup` script generated by Rails 4, but it seems like a very odd thing to include in the script.

Comment: This is a [Phusion Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/apache/restart_app.html#restart-txt) specific way.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You have to create it yourself when you want the application to restart. To do that run in a command line:

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

Comment: `touch tmp/restart.txt` in your application root directory, to be precise.

Comment: @Maurício-Linhares thank u for your reply. generally is the file created by passenger itself or must touch by manual? thank you in advance.

Comment: @ywenbo: You have to create it yourself when you want the application to restart. :)

Comment: Thank you very much.  That was NOT at all obvious from all the HOW-TOs I'd been reading over the web.